# Selecting Multiple Items from a Dynamically Generated List - Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

I am currently developing a media gallery software using Zend Framework and am trying to figure out the best way to go about adding multiple images to a gallery.  Basically, I want to be able to pull a long list of images from the database, array them on a page (possibly multiple pages using jQuery) and then allow the user to select multiple images to then Add to a gallery.  I am struggling to figure out the best practice to make this happen.

I am currently struggling with how best to create the form.  Using Zend_Form seems a bit overkill as it would essentially be a bunch of dynamically created Sub Forms (one for each image) and a single submit button.  I could simply create the form manually with HTML in the view script (creating the form and then looping through the images, each creating a new checkbox with an id to match the image ID and then let jQuery format it).

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  This is a fairly basic concept that I know I will need to do on multiple occasions throughout the application so I'd like to do it well and efficiently, hence the post here.

Thanks,
Drew

Answer (score 1):

you're right in saying Zend Form would be too much hassle.
I imagine you need something like a graphical picker, something like a page with thumbnails rather than full size images. jQuery would store the ids the user picks and then send them to your php app via an ajax post request.

First you'll need on your JS file an object which will store the values, initially empty. When a user clicks on a thumbnail (which has an "id" on its html tag and has an click jQuery event handler), you mark it visually on the UI adding a highlighted thick border (use jQuery's css for that). You also add the id of the image clicked to the object collecting the ids (via jQuery's attr) and finally you perform jQuery's load() wrapping the object to your php server which would retrieve the ids using the controller's __getParams(), store them and serve some confirmation which you may choose to display in a div replacing the image picker.

Should be easy, but feel free to ask for some code if you run into trouble

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I actually ended up using Zend Form for the initial setup for those with jQuery disabled.  Instead of creating a permanent Zend_Form file, I ended up just dynamically creating the form in the Action.  It worked nicely, but it doesn't have pagination built in yet (still to come).  Ultimately, I like your jQuery solution and will be implementing something like that in the near future.  Thanks again!